ValueError when i migrate in my Django project
I'm trying to make a music streaming website using Django. I have this error when i use the terminal command "migrate": "ValueError: Field 'song_id' expected a number but got '' ". I don't understand where "song_id" take a value that is not a number. How can i fix it and what is the code line with the problem?
this is my views.py:
def myPlaylist(request, id):
user = request.user
if user.is_authenticated:
    # Extracting Playlists of the Authenticated User
    myPlaylists = list(Playlist.objects.filter(user=user))
if user.is_authenticated:
    if request.method == "POST":
        song_id = request.POST["music_id"]
        playlist = Playlist.objects.filter(playlist_id=id).first()
        if song_id in playlist.music_ids:
            playlist.music_ids.remove(song_id)
            playlist.plays -= 1
            playlist.save()
        message = "Successfull"
        print(message)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'message': message}))
    else:
        images = os.listdir("music_app/static/PlaylistImages")
        print(images)
        randomImagePath = random.choice(images)
        randomImagePath = "PlaylistImages/" + randomImagePath
        print(randomImagePath)
        currPlaylist = Playlist.objects.filter(playlist_id=id).first()
        music_ids = currPlaylist.music_ids
        playlistSongs = []
        recommendedSingers = []
        for music_id in music_ids:
            song = Song.objects.filter(song_id=music_id).first()
            random.shuffle(recommendedSingers)
            recommendedSingers = list(set(recommendedSingers))[:6]
            playlistSongs.append(song)

        return render(request, "myPlaylist.html", {'playlistInfo': currPlaylist,
                                                       'playlistSongs': playlistSongs,
                                                       'myPlaylists': myPlaylists,
                                                       'recommendedSingers': recommendedSingers,
                                                       'randomImagePath': randomImagePath})
def addSongToPlaylist(request):
user = request.user
if user.is_authenticated:
    try:
        data = request.POST['data']
        ids = data.split("|")
        song_id = ids[0][2:]
        playlist_id = ids[1][2:]
        print(ids[0][2:], ids[1][2:])
        currPlaylist = Playlist.objects.filter(playlist_id=playlist_id).first()
        if song_id not in currPlaylist.music_ids:
            currPlaylist.music_ids.append(song_id)
            currPlaylist.plays = len(currPlaylist.music_ids)
            currPlaylist.save()
        return HttpResponse("Successfull")
    except:
        return redirect("/")
    # return redirect("/")
else:
    return redirect("/")

def likesong(request):
myPlaylists = []
try:
    # print("Request Submitted Successfully!!!")
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated:
        # Extracting Playlists of the Authenticated User
        myPlaylists = list(Playlist.objects.filter(user=user))
    if user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "POST":
            song_id = request.POST["music_id"]
            isPresent = False
            if LikedSong.objects.filter(user=user, music_id=song_id).exists():
                isPresent = True

            if isPresent:
                LikedSong.objects.filter(user=user, music_id=song_id).delete()
                # print(f"Your song is removed from the liked song id: {song_id}")
            else:
                like = LikedSong(user=user, music_id=song_id)
                like.save()
                # print(f"Your song successfully added id: {song_id}")
            message = "Successfull"
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'message': message}))
        else:
            like = LikedSong.objects.filter(user=user)
            ids = []
            for i in like:
                ids.append(i.music_id)
            preserved = Case(*[When(pk=pk, then=pos) for pos, pk in enumerate(ids)])
            likedSongs = Song.objects.filter(song_id__in=ids).order_by(preserved)
            return render(request, "likedSong.html", {'likedSongs': likedSongs})
    else:
        # print("User is not authenticated")
        return redirect("/")
except:
    return redirect("/")

and this is my models.py:
class Song(models.Model):
song_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
artist = models.CharField(max_length=50)
album = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
song = models.FileField(upload_to="media/songs/", validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['mp3', 'wav'])], default="name")
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="media/songimage/", validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'])], default="https://placehold.co/300x300/png")
data = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
slug = models.SlugField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Meta:
    ordering = ['name']


class Playlist(models.Model):
    playlist_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="name")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="media/images/", validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'])])
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name


class LikedSong(models.Model):
    liked_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    music_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="name")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name


why have you deleted your question just to ask the exact same question again ? we are volunteers and that's rude behavior

@diggusbickus because i didn't get the answer to my question and after some hours the question become not visible to new users. Thanks you for your answer of before but it didn't solve my problem, that's why i made the questiona again. I can't understand where is the problem (and why i got the down vote)

the comments help improve the quality of your question, they're an important path to problem solving. and you've discarded them for a weird reason: new users that come here to get answers too can't see your question? and i downvoted your question because obviously no effort has been made from the last time

and the django tag is relatively slow. the people that could help you didn't have the time to read your first question

The problem was the old migrations. I deleted migrations files (ex. 00XX_*.py) (NEVER delete applied migration files if you want to keep data! and don't remove the directory and init.py), i reset the DB (if you are using sqlite you can easily delete the sqlite file) and makemigrations again
